# display certain rows from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code and i only want to display a record from the table :

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['idu'];
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("bilet");
$queryreg=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oferte WHERE idu='$_SESSION['idu']' ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryreg)):
  {
    echo   $row['adresa'];
  echo  $row['descriere'] ;
  echo $row['stele'] ;
    echo $row['pret'] ;
  }
  endwhile;


?>
```

I get this error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in D:\xampp\htdocs\bilet\viz.php on line 6.

```
 The table has more then 4 rows , but i just wanna see if it works.
```

Comment: Remove endwhile thats for the alternative syntax

Comment: @meda - It's not beautiful, but it's actually legal (he's using both syntaxes)

Comment: @ChrisForrence yes you are rigjt thats why i removed my answer , i just voted yours up ! ;)

Comment: @meda - I did include your comment into my answer; while it was done correctly, you do have a valid point.

Comment: thanks guys. thanks to you I've solved this in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with...

```
$queryreg=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oferte WHERE idu='" . $_SESSION['idu'] . "'");
```

And you won't confuse to PHP interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

The specific issue has to do with your line 6 (as the error suggests). You're not properly including your session variable into the string. Try this instead:

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oferte WHERE idu='" . $_SESSION['idu'] . "'");
```

That being said, there are a few other things to keep in mind. If the user ever sets `$_SESSION['idu']`, then your code is highly vulnerable to an SQL injection attack (read up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) on how to prevent it)

---

As an aside, as @meda pointed out, you're actually using two different ways of doing while-loops. While you have it technically correct, it's certainly not a recommended way of doing such. I suggest choosing one or the other:

```
// Choice 1: Recommended
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryreg)) {
    echo $row['adresa'];
    echo $row['descriere'];
    echo $row['stele'];
    echo $row['pret'];
}

// Choice 2
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryreg)):
    echo $row['adresa'];
    echo $row['descriere'];
    echo $row['stele'];
    echo $row['pret'];
endwhile;
```